# Query regarding balanced accuracy calculation, and scoring metrics in sci-kit for comparison of balanced & imbalanced data sets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scoring

I have a small dataset of 50 data points, two classes with 25 in each class. I am doing supervised classification using cross-validation. I have trained a model using the whole dataset, but I also want to train a seperate model with 7 of the data points removed, all from one class, and see how this compares. This would leave me with 25 in the negative class and 18 in the positive. I would like to use `accuracy` as my scoring metric because it's the most widely used in my field, so I can compare my results to others.

I wanted to use this calculation of balanced accuracy: http://mvpa.blogspot.com/2015/12/balanced-accuracy-what-and-why.html for my reduced dataset, as it seems most directly comparable with accuracy for a balanced set? But the `balanced_accuracy` score in sci-kit is a different calculation (the average of recall obtained on each class).

I've read a lot around different metrics, imbalanced datasets etc and I've hit a brick wall. I don't believe there's a metric in sci-kit that performs the balanced accuracy calculation I'm after? Do I need to compute it myself using the confusion matrix? I don't know if my coding skills are good enough. Is this even the best approach to comparing two datasets, balanced and imbalanced? I know that ideally the ROC-curve should be used for balanced and the precision-recall curve for imbalanced, so that doesn't really help.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: It was a general question regarding scoring metrics, comparing imbalanced classes and calculating balanced accuracy. My apologies for not being clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is called "balanced accuracy" in the blog post you mention is strictly equivalent to `sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score`, which is an average of the recall scores, as you pointed out. To convince yourself, I reproduced the example from the blog post:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, balanced_accuracy_score

y_true = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
y_predicted = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])

print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predicted))
print("Accuracy score : %.3f" % accuracy_score(y_true, y_predicted))
print("Balanced accuracy score : %.3f" % balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_predicted))
```

Result:

```
[[9 1]
 [2 7]]
Accuracy score : 0.842
Balanced accuracy score : 0.839
```

These values match the example from the post!

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you!! I thought that they were different because I calculated the 'blog post balanced accuracy' for a confusion matrix TP =2, FP=2, FN=0, TN=4 and got 0.75, but the scikit `balanced_accuracy` score for that fold is 0.83. I must have made a mistake somewhere else... I will investigate. Thanks again.